# cURL command to check file exists or not in JFrog Artifactory

Tags: curl, artifactory

Could you please help me with below query,
API call for JFrog Artifactory to check whether a file exists or not using cURL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
curl {ArtifactoryURL}/artifactory/api/storage/{repoKey}/{filePath}
```

Please refer to this API doc here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileInfo